# link a var to an object property

Tags: javascript, express

In a file called `controllers.js`, I've got these variables :

```
var indexCtrl           = require('./index'),
    offerCtrl           = require('./offer'),
    setLocaleCtrl       = require('./setLocale'),
    specificationsCtrl  = require('./specifications');
```

and this object :

```
var routes = {
    indexCtrl: {
        'fr-FR' : '/accueil',
        'en-EN' : '/home',
        'de-DE' : '/startseite'
    },
    offerCtrl: {
        'fr-FR' : '/offre',
        'en-EN' : '/offer',
        'de-DE' : '/angebot'
    },
    setLocaleCtrl: {
        'fr-FR' : '/setLocale/:locale',
        'en-EN' : '/setLocale/:locale',
        'de-DE' : '/setLocale/:locale'
    },
    specificationsCtrl: {
        'fr-FR' : '/specifications',
        'en-EN' : '/specifications-en',
        'de-DE' : '/spezifikationen'
    }
};
```

For example, the required index.js :

```
'use strict';

var IndexModel = require('../models/index');

exports.route = function(req, res, locale) {
  console.log(locale);
  var model = new IndexModel();
  res.render('index', model);
};
```

What can I do to use the indexCtrl defined in the `var route` as the indexCtrl defined above (with the require) ?

EDIT :
For example :

```
for (var ctrl in routes) {
    var ctrlContent = routes[ctrl];
    for (var language in ctrlContent) {
        var route = ctrlContent[language];
        //router.get(route, ctrl);
        console.log('%s, %s, %s', ctrl, language, route);
    }
}
```

The log displays :

```
indexCtrl, fr-FR, /accueil
indexCtrl, en-EN, /home
indexCtrl, de-DE, /startseite
offerCtrl, fr-FR, /offre
offerCtrl, en-EN, /offer
offerCtrl, de-DE, /angebot
setLocaleCtrl, fr-FR, /setLocale/:locale
setLocaleCtrl, en-EN, /setLocale/:locale
setLocaleCtrl, de-DE, /setLocale/:locale
specificationsCtrl, fr-FR, /specifications
specificationsCtrl, en-EN, /specifications-en
specificationsCtrl, de-DE, /spezifikationen
```

That way, I know that the route `/accueil` has to be rendered in the locale fr-FR by the controller indexCtrl. But if I try to use `ctrl.route` -for example indexCtrl.route- which is defined in the require, I get an error : `Route.get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]`.

Comment: like how do you assign a variable the value of a object property?  like `var route = routes.indexCtrl`?

Comment: @tkone : In fact, I'd like to do the other way, set the var IN the property.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your question, this might do the trick:

```
var indexCtrl           = require(routes.indexCtrl[language]),
    offerCtrl           = require(routes.offerCtrl[language]),
    setLocaleCtrl       = require(routes.setLocaleCtrl[language]),
    specificationsCtrl  = require(routes.specificationsCtrl[language]);
```

Comment: `routes.indexCtrl[language]` corresponds to a route, not to a controller =/ (`/accueil` for example). So I can't access the controller thought it.